# Disable Mouse Wheel with jQuery for ID but not Class (and all children classes) Inside ID

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kde9swu/

html:

```
<div id="section-2">
  <div class="scroll_sec">
  <div class="inner">
  .... content with overflow....
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Attempting to disable the mousewheel on all of `#section-2` but at the same time allow it in the entirety of `.scroll_sec` and its contents.

jQuery:

```
$("#section-2").not( ".scroll_sec" ).bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

But, as you can see in the fiddle, still all of `#section-2` is disabled from the mousewheel, including inside `.scroll_sec`

How would I go about doing this? Apparently `.not()` is not the solution as it appears to have the same result whether or not it is included in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below CSS selector and restrict the scroll to only outside the inner div.

```js
$("#section-2").bind("mousewheel", function(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  return target.className === 'scroll_sec' ? true : false;
});
```

```css
#section-2 {
  height: 500px;
}

.scroll_sec {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-2">
  <div class="scroll_sec">
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  x<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For my minified question this works, thank you.  I am looking for something more rugged, though.  In your example, once the `scroll_sec` div scrolls all the way down to the bottom and reaches the end, `#section-2` is able to be moved by the mousewheel if the pointer is still in `scroll_sec`.  Additionally, if there are any other classes or content within `scroll_sec` it ceases to work entirely.. in my non-minified testing environment, `scroll_sec` is full of content with additional DIVs and classes. Very Basic Example of `scroll_sec` with an `inner` div: https://jsfiddle.net/9zmsayu7/1/

Comment: Hmm this in combination with yours seems to be working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/qLz7h541/ .. still messing around with it!